# How to CastRay() for Unity.Physics.SphereCollider struct without SphereCollider.Create() factory method call

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

How to CastRay() for Unity.Physics.SphereCollider struct without SphereCollider.Create() factory method call (resulting in heap allocation I presume).

Code below doesn't work and not sure why exactly:

```
using Physics = Unity.Physics;
 
bool TraceRaySphere
(
    float3 spherePos ,
    float sphereRadius ,
    float3 rayStart ,
    float3 rayEnd ,
    out Physics.RaycastHit raycastHit
)
{
    var ray = new Physics.RaycastInput{
        Start   = rayStart ,
        End     = rayEnd ,
        Filter  = Physics.CollisionFilter.Default
    };
    var geometry  = new Physics.SphereGeometry{
        Center  = spherePos ,
        Radius  = sphereRadius
    };
    var sphere = new Physics.SphereCollider{
        Geometry    = geometry ,
        Filter      = Physics.CollisionFilter.Default
    };
    return sphere.CastRay( ray , out raycastHit );
}
```

This works, but uses mentioned `SphereCollider.Create(geometry)` factory method I want to get rid of (if that's possible):

```
public static bool TraceRaySphere
(
    float3 spherePos ,
    float sphereRadius ,
    float3 rayStart ,
    float3 rayEnd ,
    out RaycastHit raycastHit
)
{
    var ray = new RaycastInput{
        Start   = rayStart ,
        End     = rayEnd ,
        Filter  = CollisionFilter.Default
    };
    var geometry  = new SphereGeometry{
        Center  = spherePos ,
        Radius  = sphereRadius
    };
    var sphereBlobAsset = SphereCollider.Create( geometry );
    bool didHit = sphereBlobAsset.Value.CastRay( ray , out raycastHit );
    sphereBlobAsset.Dispose();
    return didHit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SphereCollider` struct contains few hidden private fields that requires `Init(args)` method to be called in order to set those up with proper values:

```
public static bool TraceRaySphere
(
    float3 spherePos ,
    float sphereRadius ,
    float3 rayStart ,
    float3 rayEnd ,
    out RaycastHit raycastHit
)
{
    var ray = new RaycastInput
    {
        Start   = rayStart ,
        End     = rayEnd ,
        Filter  = CollisionFilter.Default
    };
    var geometry  = new SphereGeometry
    {
        Center  = spherePos ,
        Radius  = sphereRadius
    };
    var sphere = default(SphereCollider);
    sphere.Init( geometry , CollisionFilter.Default , Material.Default );
    return sphere.CastRay( ray , out raycastHit );
}
```

### **However**

this method is private ([chances are this may change](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-castray-on-spherecollider-struct-without-physics-spherecollider-create-allocation.984038/#post-6396377)).
To make `Init` method available you need to modify `...\com.unity.physics@0.5.0-preview.1\Unity.Physics\Collision\Colliders\Physics_SphereCollider.cs` source file and make it public.

Answer (score 1):

In my project i use following helper method to cast any Colliders (needs unsafe code execution flag because its working with the pointer)

```
public static unsafe bool ColliderCast(float3 rayFrom, float3 rayTo, quaternion rotation, CollisionWorld collisionWorld, PhysicsCollider collider)
{
    ColliderCastInput input = new ColliderCastInput()
    {
        Collider = (Collider*)collider.Value.GetUnsafePtr(),
        Orientation = rotation,
        Start = rayFrom,
        End = rayTo
    };

    return collisionWorld.CastCollider(input);
}
```

And i also have a CollisionGeome
trySingleton class which contains this

```
//Cache geometries (float3 = size, float3 = center)
private IDictionary<Tuple<float3, float3>, BoxGeometry> boxGeometries;

public BoxGeometry CreateOrGetBoxGeometry(float3 size, float3 center)
{
   
    if(this.boxGeometries == null)
    {
        this.boxGeometries = new Dictionary<Tuple<float3,float3>, BoxGeometry>();
    }

    Tuple<float3, float3> key = new Tuple<float3, float3>(size, center);

    if(!this.boxGeometries.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        this.boxGeometries.Add(key, new BoxGeometry { Size = key.Item1, Center = key.Item2, Orientation = quaternion.identity });
    }

    return this.boxGeometries[key];
}
```

This allows me to use

```
BoxCollider.Create
(
    CollisionGeomeotrySingleton.Instance.CreateOrGetBoxGeometry(5, 5), 
    CollisionFilterSingleton.Instance.CollidesWithPlayerFilter
)
```

You could go now one step further and store the BoxCollider also in the CollisionGeometrySingleton

Comment: So you suggest pre-allocating a single Collider and then reusing that allocation by casting it around - Do I understand you correctly here?
Also: Do you know why this allocation seemingly can't be bypassed?

Comment: The basic idea is that you instantiate the Collider only once using the Create method then to cache it. It can not be bypassed, since Unity Physics uses its own class structure for handling colliders (they are seperate from the usual unity collider). As soon as unity fully releases DOTS and Unity.Physics it will have support in the Editor.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is you could try to serialize the collider, or stream it in as blob asset and then only load it in your code and cache it if you really really need to bypass the create method. But this creates overhead at another place, so i see no improvement with this approach.